# Multi-page document merging Adobe Acrobat Pro

Tags: pdf, adobe, pdf-generation, acrobat

We have a number of policies (about 150 or so) we make available for download on our webpage.

Recently, Management had us move from all policies residing in one PDF to one policy per PDF.  Their reasoning was to make it easier for the end users to download the policy that they want, and to make it easier for us to replace them when they change.

Now, some end users are complaining that they want to download the whole set of policies as one large PDF.  Maintaining both formats as independent documents not only doubles our work, but increases the likelihood of error.

Since these are changed often, what I would like to do is to build a script to instruct Adobe Acrobat Pro to combine these individual policy PDFs together in a specific order.

This doesn't have to be a scrip since a GUI method would also work.

Can this be done?  If so, were can I look for examples?

Answer (score 3):

Docotic.Pdf library can merge PDF files while maintaining outline (bookmarks) structure.

There is nothing special should be done. You just append all documents one after another and that's all.

```
using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument())
{
    string[] filesToMerge = ...
    foreach (string file in filesToMerge)
        pdf.Append(file);

    pdf.Save("merged.pdf");
}
```

Comment: That would work nicely, however, I work for a state government entity.  Buying anything is exceptionally difficult and time-consuming.  I might be able to convince the powers-that-be to buy it, but the first question I will be asked "isn't there another way."